# Using "if" function with 2 parameters

Tags: excel

If A1 = 12/31/2012(year end)
B1 = Corporation, Individual, trust etc (type of entity)
I want C1 to compute the date the tax return will be due  Based on ye and type of entity, due date  will be 3.5 or 2.5 months from year end.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What *exactly* do you want the calculation to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the formula something like below:

```
=IF(criteria, A1+74, A1+105 )
```

Criteria as you define.

74: number of days (1st 2.5 months in the non-leap year)
105: number of days (1st 3.5 months in the non-leap year)

Or as pnuts suggests:

```
=IF(criterion,EOMONTH(A1,3)-15,EOMONTH(A1,4)-15)
```